# Django - how to display an object's field names and attributes, excluding null ones?

Tags: python, django

So say I have a model of which there are some fields that might not be filled in:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    location = models.CharField(blank=True)
    comment = models.Charfield(blank=True)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(SomeOtherThing, related_name='things')
```

I need a way to display the info about an instance of this object in a template, showing the field names and the value of them(only if it is filled in), like so:

```
The page with the thing on it

name: my awesome thing
location: wisconsin
comment: love this thing!
uploader: joe schmoe
```

if, for example, comment were not filled in, I would only want to display the fields that are, not have the field name and a blank value:

```
The page with the thing on it 
name: my awesome thing
location: wisconsin
uploader: joe schmoe
```

Is there some kind of way to do this simply in django? I know there is some kind of method to convert an object into a dict, but this doesn't solve the problem of excluding null fields. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `model_to_dict` method, and iterate over the dictionary like this:

```
{% for key, value in dictionary.items %}
  {% if value %}
    <p>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works well, thank you. One question, is there any specific way the fields are ordered? Because they are not in the same order as they are in my model.

Answer (score 0):

```
thing = Thing.objects.get(pk=1)
for field_name in Thing._meta.get_all_field_names():
    if getattr(thing, field_name):
        print field_name, getattr(thing, field_name)
```